# Override Django Admin Save Model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to override Django form save method to be able to create multiple objects at once.

I have an AvailableHours model :

```
class AvailableHours(models.Model):
    free_date = models.ForeignKey(AvailableDates,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='freedate')
    free_hours_from = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    free_hours_to = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,)
    status = models.BooleanField(null=True,default=True,)
```

and I have a ModelForm for this class :

```
class TimeGenerator(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AvailableHours

        fields = ['free_date','free_hours_from','free_hours_to','status']  

    def save(self, commit=True):
        base_item = super().save(commit=False)
        frm = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']
        to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_to']
        items = [
            AvailableHours(
                free_date=base_item.free_date,
                status=base_item.status,
                free_hours_from=hour,
                free_hours_to=hour + 1,
            )
            for hour in range(frm, to)
        ]
        if commit:
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)
        return items
```

I want to create multiple AvailableHours object like this: if the form is set free_hours_from = 13 and free_hours_to=16 so the save method creates 13-14 , 14-15, 15-16
I achieved this by overriding my ModelForm but now I want to override Admin Save model to do this from Django Admin.

I tried by doing it like this in admin.py

```
class AvailableHoursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, commit=True):
        base_item = super().save(commit=False)
        frm = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_from']
        to = self.cleaned_data['free_hours_to']
        items = [
            AvailableHours(
                free_date=base_item.free_date,
                status=base_item.status,
                free_hours_from=hour,
                free_hours_to=hour + 1,
            )
            for hour in range(frm, to)
        ]
        if commit:
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)
        return items
admin.site.register(AvailableHours,AvailableHoursAdmin)
```

but no luck.

anyone has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all answers from contributors below,

I managed to fix the issues with @Mahammadhusain answer regarding making extra object.

```
@admin.register(AvailableHours)
class AvailableHoursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #form = TimeGenerator
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        frm = obj.free_hours_from
        to = obj.free_hours_to
        date =obj.free_date
        # Ensure from-to range is valid and create objects within the range
        if frm is not None and to is not None:
            items = [
                AvailableHours(
                    free_date=obj.free_date,
                    status=obj.status,
                    free_hours_from=hour,
                    free_hours_to=hour + 1,
                )
                for hour in range(frm, to)
            ]
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)
            
            extra = AvailableHours.objects.get(
                free_hours_from = frm ,
                free_hours_to = to ,
                free_date=date ,
                )
            extra.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent creating an additional object that spans the entire range, you can modify the logic to exclude the upper limit in the range.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import AvailableHours

class AvailableHoursAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        frm = obj.free_hours_from
        to = obj.free_hours_to

        # Ensure 'from' is before 'to' and create objects within the range
        if frm is not None and to is not None and frm < to:
            range_limit = min(to, frm + 24)  # Limit the range to 24 hours max
            items = [
                AvailableHours(
                    free_date=obj.free_date,
                    status=obj.status,
                    free_hours_from=hour,
                    free_hours_to=min(hour + 1, range_limit),  # Limit 'to' within the range_limit
                )
                for hour in range(frm, range_limit)
            ]
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)

admin.site.register(AvailableHours, AvailableHoursAdmin)
```

updated code uses **`range(frm, to)`** in the list comprehension, which creates objects from **`free_hours_from`** up to, but excluding, **`free_hours_to`**. Thus, it avoids creating an extra object that spans the entire range specified by the **`free_hours_from`** and **`free_hours_to`** fields.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but this way it creates an additional 13-16 as well as the rest. you forgot to handle that exception. can you fix the code ?

Comment: didnt work. still creating an extra object from first hour till last hour . eg 13-16

Comment: i dont get it. its still creating the extra object from-to

Comment: pl check answer is updated

Comment: sorry now code updated

Comment: that just made things worse. now when i input 13-16 it makes :
13-14
14-15
13-16

Comment: try with for hour in range(frm, to - 1)

Comment: nah didnt work. i think best approach would be to add a delete to remove that 1 extra object after bult create

Comment: if len(items) > 1:
                items.pop()  # Remove the last item to exclude the upper limit
            AvailableHours.objects.bulk_create(items)

Comment: same as before when I input 13-16 it makes : 13-14 14-15 13-16

Comment: when you give input 13-16 then what you want ??

Comment: 13-14
14-15
15-16

not 13-16

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256021/discussion-between-mahammadhusain-kadiwala-and-essiprog).

Comment: check now the to  + 1

Comment: still making extra object

Comment: now do some changes

# Add the object for 'to' value separately

Comment: no it made 2 extra objects. one beyond the time limit . and the old one from-to

Comment: # Limit the range to 24 hours max

Comment: still the same.

Comment: check with range_limit code updated